# How to put a container with items (e.g. products on a e-commerce site) beside a vertical nav bar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        .col {
            border: solid black 1px;
            margin: 10px 20px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Page Container -->
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="mt-5">
        <navbar>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu item 1</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </navbar>

        <!-- Products Wrapper -->
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column d-inline">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row row-cols-3">
                    <div class="col">Product 1</div>
                    <div class="col">Product 2</div>
                    <div class="col">Product 3</div>
                    <div class="col">Product 4</div>
                    <div class="col">Product 5</div>
                    <div class="col">Product 6</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am struggling to find the right grid (structure) to use in my html doc (I am trying to replicate an e-commerce website). I have a vertical nav bar at the left of my document, and I want to add, at the right of this menu, 3 products per row (row-cols-3). Do you have any idea of how I can do that? (example : https://www.aritzia.com/en/search?cgid=tshirts-cropped&lastViewed=61)

Comment: nobody, and I really do mean nobody, on this sites wants to look at a jpg of code!  We can't do anything with it.  Please show your code as plain text

Comment: Sorry! My code is upload now!

Answer (score 0):

you could do something with the ul tag.

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <div style="float:left">
      1
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      2
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      3
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="float:left">
      1
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      2
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      3
    </div>
  </li>
    <li>
    <div style="float:left">
      1
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      2
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      3
    </div>
  </li>
    <li>
    <div style="float:left">
      1
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      2
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      3
    </div>
  </li>
    <li>
    <div style="float:left">
      1
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      2
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      3
    </div>
  </li>
    <li>
    <div style="float:left">
      1
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      2
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      3
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of your desired layout using only native [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/) components. Additionally, I've included responsive classes so the layout will adjust to various screen sizes.

The [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/) explains each of the components used which are listed below:

- [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/)
- [Nav](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/)
- [Card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container my-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item my-3">
          Categories
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">T-Shirts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blouses</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sweaters</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pants</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shorts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skirts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dresses</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Jackets & Coats</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accessories</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item my-3">
            Categories
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">T-Shirts</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blouses</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sweaters</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pants</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shorts</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skirts</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dresses</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Jackets & Coats</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accessories</a>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3">
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=1" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=2" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=3" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=4" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=5" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=6" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=7" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=8" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=9" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=10" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=11" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=12" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=13" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=14" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=15" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180?random=16" class="card-img-top" alt="Sunday Best, Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee, $20">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Sunday Best</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Candy T-Shirt, Embroidered tee</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">$20 Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MarilouAudet No problem. If it was helpful, indicating the answer as a solution will help others find as well.